# Входная строка имела неверный формат в Int32.Parse

Tags: c#, winforms

Столкнулся со странной ошибкой. Есть кнопка button, и событие Click для неё. В обработчике события Click мы делаем следующее:

```
static Button ok = new Button();
static TextBox tb = new TextBox();
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tb.Width = 60;
    tb.Height = 20;
    tb.Location = new Point(214, 115);
    Controls.Add(tb);  //добавляем TextBox на форму
    ok.Width = 60;
    ok.Height = 20;
    ok.Location = new Point(214, 135);
    ok.Text = "OK";
    ok.Click += click;  //событие Click для кнопки
    Controls.Add(ok);  //добавляем кнопку
}
```

Ну тут мы просто добавляем на форму TextBox и кнопку. А дальше в click мы делаем следующее:

```
int result;
if (Int32.Parse(tb.Text) != 9)  //входная строка имела неверный формат 
    result = Int32.Parse(tb.Text) - 1;
else
    result = 0;
//мой код, полный тайн и загадок (tb тут я не трогаю)
Controls.Remove(ok);
tb.Text = "";
Controls.Remove(tb);
```

Но на 2 строке ошибка "Входная строка имела неверный формат. Причём, эта ошибка вылетает в случайный момент, когда я повторяю эти действия (нажимаю  на button, ввожу число, нажимаю на ok). Что делаю не так?

Comment: Вы присваиваете tb.text пустую строку, может быть, проблема в этом? В вопрос не вникал, сходу в глаза только это бросается.

Comment: Например, вводите не число? Ставьте пробел? Есть много вариантов как вести не число. Или, например, ничего не вводите.

Comment: А вы не пробовали посмотреть в отладчике что содержится в свойстве Text элемента TextBox во время возникновения ошибки? Ведь Visual Studio позволяет это сделать.

Comment: Да, с помощью отладчика посмотрел - на 2 раз tb.Text равен пустой строке. Но ввожу всё правильно, без пробелов, значит, нужно по другому это всё реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

По нажатию на button3_Click вы добавляете назад на форму тот же текстбокс tb и ту же кнопку ok. И каждый раз дополнительно подписываетесь на ok.Click. Каждая дополнительная подписка вызывает еще одно срабатывание обработчика при нажатии.

В первый раз ваш код click вызывается один раз. Выполняется

```
click
    Int32.Parse(tb.Text)
    tb.Text = "";
```

Второй раз клик на кнопку вызывает метод click два раза подряд (т.к. код код button3_Click вызвался дважды, и строка `ok.Click += click` выполнилась дважды)

```
click
    Int32.Parse(tb.Text)
    tb.Text = "";
click
    Int32.Parse(tb.Text) <-- падает
    tb.Text = "";
```

Фикс - не использовать повторно объекты ok / tb, а создавать новый текстбокс и новую кнопку при каждом нажатии на button3:

```
static Button ok;
static TextBox tb;
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ok = new Button();
    tb = new TextBox();

    tb.Width = 60;
    tb.Height = 20;
    tb.Location = new Point(214, 115);
    Controls.Add(tb);  //добавляем TextBox на форму
    ok.Width = 60;
    ok.Height = 20;
    ok.Location = new Point(214, 135);
    ok.Text = "OK";
    ok.Click += click;  //событие Click для кнопки
    Controls.Add(ok);  //добавляем кнопку
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, правда, нашёл уже другое решение, но ваше мне нравится больше!